# C++ Determining empty cells from reading in data

Tags: c++, c++11, parsing, stdstring, istringstream

I'm reading in data from a csv file that has some columns ending before others, i.e.:

```
0.01 0.02 0.01
0.02      0.02
```

And I'm trying to figure out how to catch these empty locations and what to do with them. My current code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
int main(){

//Code that reads in the data, determines number of rows & columns

//Set up array the size of all the cells (including empty):
double *ary = new double[cols*rows]; //Array of pointers
double var;
std::string s;
int i = 0, j = 0;

while(getline(data,line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);    //Each line in a string
    while(iss >> var)                //Send cell data to placeholder
    {
        ary[i*cols+j] = var;
        j+=1;
    }
    i+=1;
}
```

How can I determine if the cell is empty? I want to convert these to "NaN" somehow. Thank you!

Comment: Is each number guaranteed to be of the form `X.XX`? Or will some have more digits?

Comment: Then you need to read each line per se then do some parsing.

Comment: That's not a CSV file.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: CVS files use comma as the separator. (comma separator values).

Comment: I was just posting an example of the data. It varies; looks like this: 9 0 0
12 0.0001 0.0001. @Raindrop7 how would I do that? I just found this and will look into it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c#1120224

Comment: @Raindrop7 that might be part of the point Neil's trying to make, but CSV is much deeper than simply comma separated tokens these days.

Comment: It's a table in LibreOffice Calc that I saved as a .csv file, with the column delimiter being a tab. Regardless of the point, Neil your comment doesn't really help with anything

Comment: @Raindrop There are no commas in the user's data and it's "CSV", not "CVS". So I don't see what your point is.

Comment: First thing to do is to save it with delimiter being a comma - you will find that easier to read and to parse.

Comment: @wobertson do yourself a favour and build a simple wrapper structure around `double *ary` and it's indexing math. It'll make it a lot easier to pass around. Here is an example: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op By the way, good call on making a single array rather than an array of arrays.

Comment: Yo that looks like a good idea @user4581301, thanks for that

Comment: stream operator `>>` is blind to all forms of whitespace. A tab and a space all mean the same thing. It cannot detect an empty token for you. Look into `getline(iss, token, '\t')` and then converting var into a number.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I'll try that, I found an answer that talks about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c#1120224, but what's wrong with using '\t' instead of ',' as the delimiter? Or, how does the comma help?

Comment: Ahhhhh okay @user4581301 that answers my previous question. Okay  thanks!

Comment: Why comma is better wraps around to the same sort of problem as `>>`. At a glance you can distinguish commas from spaces, but you can't necessarily distinguish tabs from spaces. The computer doesn't care, they have different numeric values, but the human eye is easily fooled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like follows.
Get the inputs, line by line and using  `(std::getline(sstr, word, ' '))` you can set the deliminator to `' '` and the rest is checking weather the scanned word is empty or not.

If it's empty, we will set it to `NaN`(only once).

```
Input:
0.01 0.02 0.01
0.02      0.02
0.04      0.08
```

Here is the output:
[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::fstream file("myfile.txt");
    std::vector<std::string> vec;

    if(file.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        bool Skip = true;

        while(std::getline(file, line))
        {
            std::stringstream sstr(line);
            std::string word;

            while (std::getline(sstr, word, ' '))
            {
                if(!word.empty())
                    vec.emplace_back(word);

                else if(word.empty() && Skip)
                {
                    vec.emplace_back("NaN");
                    Skip = false;
                }
            }
            Skip = true;
        }
        file.close();
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << vec[i] << " ";
        if((i+1)%3 ==0) std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```